# Make desktop client work with newer EF db migration without updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, desktop-application, entity-framework-migrations

Currently I have an ERP which is a Winforms based client (with SQL Server), which gets delivered and updated on desktops using ClickOnce.

The current version is using Entity Framework 4 (ObjectContext-based) and database first. The way I am doing updates to the client when there's a database schema change is a four step process:

1. Create an intermediary updated database schema on production with compatible columns (allow null everywhere or have a default value, etc.). Old clients can connect to that database and keep working as if nothing was changed
2. Update desktop clients to an intermediary version with the updated features which accounts for this intermediary schema but has all "final schema" features
3. Once all clients are updated and all records are compatible with the "final" schema, make a new update on the schema with the needed database constraints
4. Update all clients to a final version which is mapped to this final schema (which accounts for database constraints errors, and need those schema changes to work).

I've found this process to be, if a bit cumbersome to us, better for the clients, who can update when they see fit, and don't get interrupted with an update in the middle of their work (which may involve having customers in front of them who don't want to wait for a software update).

Now I have made an almost-complete rewrite of the client (still Winforms), using EF6 and code-first, with migrations.

I've been searching for documentation but can't find anything (seems there's only web programming these days, where generally updates to the database and the web client can be done simultaneously and without interrupting users), but once I apply migrations on production, non-updated clients can no longer work with the database. EF will complain and throw exceptions upon instantiating the context if it's not up to date with the database schema.

Specific question: is there a way to have an EF6 code-first dbcontext to work with a newer migration of the database schema than the one compiled-in, as long as it is compatible? If that's the case, I could just keep doing what I was doing so far.

And an (I guess) oppinion based question if anyone wants to extend on the actual answer: is there any better way to handle this scenario? I'm sure I'm not the only one having this problem, however the keywords needed to Google for documentation are too broad and so far, only web scenarios have come up on my searches.

I'm currently at a stage on the client rewrite where major changes could be allowed, so I don't care if the solution may complicate parts of the code

Comment: Try to manually delete the __MigrationHistory and EdmMetadata tables (probably there is only one of this) in a non updated system and run the application. If you don't get the error, please, let me know and I'll add this as answer with further explanations.

Comment: It actually works! I'd have never thought it'd do (I was expecting the dbcontext instancing to fail if there was no `__MigrationHistory` table and there was a `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class defined in the project). With this information, I can already work it out, but if you want to expand as an answer, please do and I'll upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an application initializes the model database, etiher by directly calling `DbContext.Database.Initialize` or instancing the first `DbContext`, it checks if the model in the application and the model in the database match.

To do so, it calculates the model hash, and compares it with the hash stored in the `__MigrationHistory` table (or in the `EdmMetadata` table, if it was updated from EF 4.x). This is done in the [`System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/ModelCompatibilityChecker.cs) method, which receives a parameter named `throwIfNoMetadata` which happens to be `false` in the internal implementation, so no exception is thrown if there is no metadata.

So, if you make this tables dissapear in some way before the database is initialized, you'll avoid the error. The important point is that you must do this change without using `DbContext`. If not, the database will try to initialize, and, if this table exists, it will fail. So you can use plain `ADO.NET` to drop the tables.

Take into account that the metadata tables can be automatically created, for example by applying migrations.

You can also use `ctx.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)` to check if the database metadata exists and is compatible or not, to get rid of it. The parameter is precisely the `throwIfNoMetadata` that I mention above.

### Compatibility check in db initializers:

The default DB Initializer is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, and it does check the model compatibilty with the `throwIfNoMetadata` set to `false`. That's why this solution works. However, if you implement your own version of DB Initializer that doesn'd run the check, it shuld work.

```
public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
{
    Check.NotNull(context, "context");

    var existence = new DatabaseTableChecker().AnyModelTableExists(context.InternalContext);

    if (existence == DatabaseExistenceState.Exists)
    {
        // If there is no metadata either in the model or in the database, then
        // we assume that the database matches the model because the common cases for
        // these scenarios are database/model first and/or an existing database.
        if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false, existenceState: existence))
        {
            throw Error.DatabaseInitializationStrategy_ModelMismatch(context.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Either the database doesn't exist, or exists and is considered empty
        context.Database.Create(existence);
        Seed(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Given the explanation, which makes perfect sense... would it work if I just replaced the database initializer with one that does nothing (using `Database.SetInitializer`) so that I don't have to remove the table? Removing the table would be easy, just add it to the production-schema-update script, but I'd rather have a 1:1 copy on the staging database

Comment: with initializer set to null, the CompatibleWithModel method should not run. However I heard some collegues encountering weird errors with not compatible __MigrationHistory, even with null initializer.

Comment: It most probably would, but I'm not completely sure. I don't know it the model compatibilty is checked somewhere else. I think this could work because initializers like `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` check the model compatibilty to take further actions.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I was thinking of having an empty initializer, instead of `null` (which I'm sure it'll be somehow different ;-) ), but I guess I can just make some tests. Thanks to both

Comment: @JotaBe will try to remember to update, but I have some way to go before I'm on that point to test throughoutly (my question came because I was doing some updates today to the old client and started wondering how would I do that on the new code-first one)

Comment: @JotaBe just making sure, isn't `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` the default initializer? I'd be worried to put something in production if `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` was the default one

Comment: My previous comment was wrong. The default DB initializer is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` and this also checks for model compatibility if the DB already exists. I'm updating my answer.